# Why did my UPS works as expected if unplugged from wall, but seemingly failed when an actual power disruption occurred?

Tags: usb, power-supply, power, webcam

I've got several UPS units protecting my various devices. Today the room lights flickered for a minute, I heard a UPS "clicking" sound, and got notifications from my Mac that a few of my external hard drives and my USB camera were "disconnected without being ejected".

Checking, I saw that the devices were all plugged into UPSs (except the webcam, which needs no separate power) and their USB cords are all plugged into a USB hub.

The UPS is a Cyberpower 750VA unit, and the hub is a:

> "Powered USB Hub - ACASIS 16 Ports 90W USB 3.0 Data Hub - with Individual On/Off Switches and 12V/7.5A Power"

Why would any of the devices even know about what seems to be a power glitch, if the UPS was doing its job?

To test if it's going bad, I pulled its power cord out of the wall outlet, and absolutely nothing happened - it beeped, but none of the devices reported anything wrong, so it seems to be working correctly?

My question is: If pulling the UPS plug out of the wall doesn't cause a problem (it seems to be isolating the devices from power problems), what natural event caused the disconnected errors - how did it get past the UPS and what can I do about it?

Comment: How a UPS reacts to different kinds of power disruptions depends entirely on the type of the UPS. From the behavior I'd guess this one doesn't have a power conditioner, but it's just a backup battery unit. [Here](https://ehomerecordingstudio.com/uninterruptible-power-supply/)'s a pretty good article describing different types of UPS:s.

Comment: It seems possible that your backup power unit is not a real UPS and the power flicker was shorter than the transition time (milliseconds) for the backup power unit to transfer to battery. You may need to get a true UPS.

Comment: Ok so let's say that the first few milliseconds of a disruption is not handled by the UPS. Then when I pull the plug out of the wall, that should happen, followed by the UPS kicking on. So my devices should have complained when I pulled the plug - the first few milliseconds should have tripped them, and then power would have come back to them from the UPS. That didn't happen, so it seems to me that it can't just be the UPS being slow to respond to power loss, right?

Comment: It is possible that a really short power blip is shorter than your backup unit transmission time. 1/2 cycle blip is 8 ms. Some backup units take 10 to 12 ms to transition. That is what you are seeing.

Comment: I looked it up and the UPS I have says it's "line interactive", which according to the article cited by Peregrino69, should be good enough?  Seems like if the first 8ms was what was tripping things, my pulling the plug out of the wall should have done it.  This is what I have: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001E08PF2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1  - is there a better model - what should I be looking at besides just "line interactive"? Performance is more important than cost for this application.

Comment: There other possibility is a drop followed by a surge and the backup unit thinks it does not have to turn on.  Your only real solution is a true UPS.

Comment: Ok so line-interactive isn't good enough for this, I need "Online UPS"?

Comment: I have posted an answer for you.

Comment: Was the powered USB hub plugged into a UPS?

Comment: **Do not test a UPS by unplugging it from the wall socket.** That would remove the  grounding, and the charged battery & circuit providing 120VAC to the PC is now floating.  That's a hazard (you become the likely path to ground)  that should be avoided by using a switched outlet instead.

Comment: As I noted in my answer you can break the AC circuit at the panel which maintains ground.

Comment: *"The UPS is a Cyberpower 750VA unit"* -- You could be more specific with a model number or link.  Besides the PSU for the USB hub, what else was powered by the UPS?  If these other devices (e.g. the Mac?) were not affected by the brownout, then the PSU for the USB hub could be the weak link (or a bad combination with that UPS).

Answer (score 0):

> Ok so let's say that the first few milliseconds of a disruption is not
> handled by the UPS. Then when I pull the plug out of the wall, that
> should happen, followed by the UPS kicking on. So my devices should
> have complained when I pulled the plug - the first few milliseconds
> should have tripped them, and then power would have come back to them
> from the UPS. That didn't happen, so it seems to me that it can't just
> be the UPS being slow to respond to power loss, right?

It is not possible to document all the short term blips that may occur. That is what you are seeing and I do not use the backup units like you have for computers.

So if you mean by Online UPS that the AC comes from the battery and AC generation unit inside, then yes, that is what you need.

In my UPS (APC UPS) the AC plug serves only to charge the UPS battery. Inside the battery runs an AC inverter and that is what powers the computer.

My UPS is an APC (Schneider Electric) XL750 UPS like the one below but some years older so not exactly the same.

[True UPS](https://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/APC-Smart-UPS-XL-750VA-USB-Serial-120V/P-SUA750XL?isCurrentSite=true)

To verify how my unit operates, I attached an oscilloscope to the UPS output (the connection to the computer and network) and displayed 3 cycles. There was no dropout or disturbance on the waveform, which is to be expected in a true UPS.

Any external AC disconnection can be done at the electrical panel (circuit breaker) and not by unplugging the UPS Unit. But this will display the type of AC disconnection you get.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: So you're referring to an "online UPS" - you're saying that "line interactive" UPSs like mine are not sufficient to avoid such glitches?  can you point to a specific APC model?

Comment: I did so.. APC XL750.  That or like (somewhat more powerful) model will do fine.

Comment: I looked it up, I think - is it this: https://www.amazon.com/APC-Smart-UPS-SmartConnect-Uninterruptible-SMT750C/dp/B074P4NJWL/ref=sr_1_7?dchild=1&keywords=APC+XL750&qid=1633367948&sr=8-7 - it also says "line interactive", just like mine. It doesn't seem to be an "online UPS". Is there some other aspect that I should be looking for? otherwise it says "line interactive" just like mine so I can't figure out what's different.

Comment: That unit is a battery backup. Mine is like this:  https://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/APC-Smart-UPS-XL-750VA-USB-Serial-120V/P-SUA750XL?isCurrentSite=true (Trur UPS)  I added the link to my answer to be definitive.

Comment: understood, thank you for making the detailed test. My question is basically: how do we tell, from a web page description, whether a given model is like yours, or like mine, given that both are labeled the same: "line interactive". What aspect of the product description allows us to see which one will be the better one, for choosing models in the future?

Comment: Once you decide on a unit or two, you need to get the Manufacturer's detailed specifications and may need to inquire if you have any questions.

Comment: Your UPS is not an online UPS (or true UPS) (as you claim) but rather is line-interactive (as @mlevin77 points out).  Read the technical specifications in the link that you provided.

Comment: The unit I purchased (several years ago) when APC was APC  most definitely is a true UPS. Models today are different which I why I suggested getting technical specs.

Comment: Keep in mind that much depends on the quality and design of any piece of equipment. The information I posted is not misinformation. It holds for the unit I have.

Comment: ok so how to recognize a "decent UPS" when purchasing - before you have it and can put an oscilloscope on it - how to choose a product? Do they publish switchover speed, or what parameter to look for in the technical specs? Mine appears to be a reputable "line-interactive" model and still it wasn't good enough.

Comment: Yes. I have a battery backup on my TV set and cable box  (no issue if a short outage).  APC (Schneider) says average transition is under 8 ms.